# How to reload implicitly linked dll

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I am facing one problem with implicitly linked dll.
I have one application written in C++ which is implicitly linked to dll.
After particular number of iteration, the dll functions do not work as per expectations.
I want to reload this dll so that the freshly loaded dll work properly.
The problem is that since the dll is linked implicitly to the application, I am not able to reload the dll during runtime.
Is there any way so that the implicitly linked dll can reload again?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to fix the bug in your DLL than implemmenting some unload/reload hack?

Comment: You can unload it, call LoadLibrary once and FreeLibrary twice.  This will rarely come to a good end, your code still contains calls to the unloaded DLL.  Maybe they still work after you call LoadLibrary again.  That's a crap shoot with zero odds when the DLL got rebased.

Comment: John, the dll I am using is third party dll and we don't have the source code of it.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot force a re-load of an implicitly linked DLL. You will need to use explicit linking.

Answer (score 2):

I'm facing the same issue. What I did is that I created an interface class. The class that implements the interface loads the dll in its constructor (LoadLibrary), and unloads it on the destructor (FreeLibrary).

A quick note: This approach is working fine with Visual Studio 2008, but for some reason, it's not working with visual studio 98